# Angular 5: Using Service from inside Custom Decorator Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, decorator

I'm creating a `@Log()` Decorator Function for debugging purposes;

I want that Decorator to delegate some of it's logic to a `LoggingService` that in turn depends on other services from the app...

I've been trying a lot of different things, the simplest/most straightforward way was to cache the Main (or Shared) Module's Injector as a static prop on the module itself (see StackBlitz example linked below), and that works for lazy-loaded modules, but not for eagerly loaded ones...

Non-working poc: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1bpvx?file=app%2Fdecorator.ts

Is there a way I could mkae use of that Service in there??

Thanks!

Comment: The question [should contain all related code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please, update it. The link may become broken with time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class decorator is executed once on class definition. In order to avoid race condition when calling `AppModule.injector.get(LoggingService)` it should be moved to the place where `AppModule.injector` is already defined, i.e. class method.

It [should be](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7cr5uj?file=app%2Fdecorator.ts):

```
constructor.prototype[hook] = function (args) {
  const loggingService = AppModule.injector.get(LoggingService);

  loggingService.log({ ... })
  ...
```

This also creates tight coupling with `AppModule` and prevents the units from being reused or tested separately from it. It's recommended to use another object to hold `injector` property, e.g. assign `injector` not in main but in child module that is imported into `AppModule`:

```
export class InjectorContainerModule { 
  static injector: Injector;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    InjectorContainerModule.injector = injector;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is better than mine.

Comment: Damn I want to facepalm so hard now...!  - Thanks for opening my eyes :)

Comment: @estus Great point to create a child module, to get rid of the circular dependency. But how to access the root injector in the `InjectorContainerModule`? Assign root injector to the child module explicitly, or import the `LoggingService` in the `InjectorContainerModule` rather than the `AppModule`?

Comment: You don't need any additional measures to do that. `Injector` is root injector in InjectorContainerModule, unless the module was lazily loaded.

Comment: Thanks for this example. Is there anyway to call an injected service without having an instance created of that decorated component?  For example, I'm trying to create a decorator that will maintain a dictionary of strings to Type<any> (components).  Simply: "FooComponent": FooComponent, "BarComponent": BarComponent - for translating DB driven dynamic forms which have strings stored in the DB.  I would like to use injection if possible, but using the NgINit hook only works when an instance is created already.  I intend to use this to create the instance within my dynamic form service...

Comment: @AdamPlocher I'm not sure if I understood your case correctly. Consider asking a new question that explains it in details. Even if it's not possible, there could be alternative ways.

Comment: Basically, a svc that converts string to type StringToComponentSvc.convert("MyComponent") - returns Type<any> which is the actual type MyComponent. Add decorator called "@Register" to all components that should be "known" to the service.  I have it working with a static dictionary, but would ideally have the decorator call into the same service and register the components in a non-static dictionary within the service itself. Needs to run on all classes with the decorator (not just instantiated instances). Sorry yes this is getting borderline thread-hijackish. Will ask a new q and post url :)

Answer (score 2):

Try [stackblitz fixed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5yndx?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)

This will print

> LoggingService: HelloComponent - ngOnInit was called

Minor changes - basically using `ReflectiveInjector` as in [angular Injector#example](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#example)

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';

const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  {provide: 'loggingService', useClass: LoggingService}
]);

const loggingService = injector.get('loggingService');
```

I am sure you can use `useExisting` and use `LoggingService` as provider in your app module.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that ReflectiveInjector creates a new injector. The OP states that *LoggingService that in turn depends on other services from the app...*. This requirement wasn't reflected in the example but will likely create problems, because those services won't be same instances as the ones in app injector.

Comment: Good comment and approach, but selected Estus' answer because of his comment - Thanks for the help!