# Passing objects to custom decorator from angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, decorator

The problem is pretty simple I think.
I have my custom decorator which need some object to proper running. 
This object is some service which I have provided for my component. So that I want to pass this service into the decorator.

This is some example of code:

```
@Component({...})
export class TestComponent {

   constructor(private service: TestService){}

   @MyDecorator(service)
   run(){
     ...
   }

}
```

Obviously, this approach is bad because the `service` isn't accessible at the moment when is passed in `MyDecorator`.

What should I do?

Comment: shouldn't you pass it using @MyDecorator(this.service) ?

Comment: this isn't the right scope

Comment: As an idea : I never tried anything like that but : perhaps you can use the angular Injector https://angular.io/api/core/Injector (and only give the service name to your Decorator. But the question is also how to have access to Injector service since it need to be injecte. Perhaps you can define it in a global object (exemple window, brrrr ugly) who will be accessible inside your decorator.

Comment: ah it's look like someone add a similare idea :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632841/angular-5-using-service-from-inside-custom-decorator-function

Comment: hmm it looks ugly, but maybe this is the only solution :<

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little bit late, but i solved the problem by wrapping it in a function.

```
// OBJECT THAT WE WILL PASS
class SomeKindOfObject {}

// DECORATOR
function Decorator(type: ()=>object){
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    console.log(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
  };
}

// CLASS WRAPPED WITH FUNCTION
function component<T extends object>(classRef: T){
  class Component{

    @Decorator( () => classRef )
    find() {
      console.log(classRef);
    }

  }
  return Component;
}

// CLASS USAGE
const comp =  new (component(SomeKindOfObject));
comp.find();


// INHERITANCE USAGE
class Component2 extends component(SomeKindOfObject){}
```

Note - i didn't make this example specifically for angular, but i was having a similar problem in nestjs, hope this helps someone.